# Eclipse - possible to have permanent breakpoints, or two Breakpoints tabs?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As the number of breakpoints builds up during a phase of development, or during debugging a single issue, it's usually necessary to clear all of the current breakpoints when moving to another issue/phase.

Is there a way to have a 2nd Breakpoints tab, where permanent Breakpoints could be left intact i.e. for intermittent issues we sometimes leave breakpoints active while fixing numerous other issues.... this makes clearing all Breakpoints a real hassle

Brian

P.S. I'm aware of using logging instead of these longer term breakpoints

Comment: You may want to vote for implementation of this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=155333. That would allow  Mylyn to automatically store/restore your breakpoints, depending on the task that you work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group and assign breakpoints in working sets to achieve this:

[image]

In addition you may export or import them to transfer breakpoints between projects or store them with your project.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just to note for others, use Group By>Breakpoint Working Set to view/delete breakpoints within sets, and when deleting, select the working set, and hit the single X.